# Trying to get the version number but application crashes

Tags: android, eclipse, version, crash-reports

I want to get the version number of my application but the application crashes upon load when I try it.

```
int currentVersionCode;
try {
    currentVersionCode = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            this.getApplicationInfo().packageName, 0).versionCode;
    Toast.makeText(this, currentVersionCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    return;
}
```

LogCat:

```
04-05 16:01:43.108: D/LocationManager(1109): Constructor: service = android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy@44c0f748
04-05 16:01:43.198: W/ResourceType(1109): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000001
04-05 16:01:43.208: D/AndroidRuntime(1109): Shutting down VM
04-05 16:01:43.208: W/dalvikvm(1109): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-05 16:01:43.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1109): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{weather.right.now/weather.right.nowActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:200)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at weather.right.nowActivity.onCreate(nowActivity.java:58)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-05 16:01:43.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     ... 11 more
04-05 16:01:43.248: I/dalvikvm(1109): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-05 16:01:43.258: I/dalvikvm(1109): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

How can I fix my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float currentVersionCode;
try {
    currentVersionCode = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            this.getApplicationInfo().packageName, 0).versionCode;
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+currentVersionCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    return;
}
```

Try this...a minor change

use the below for your reference...

```
String versionName = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0 ).versionName;
```

Comment: Hm. How wierd. It prints 1.0 :S Woa! Wait! `android:versionName` is on 1.3, not `android:versionCode`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing the version to Toast.makeText as an int. If you pass an int to makeText it assumes it's a String resource ID. This is why you are getting a string resource not found error.

Convert the version code to a String, before passing it to makeText.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String` when I changed `int currentVersionCode;` to `String currentVersionCode;`

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, ""+currentVersionCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: @Agarwal: Thanks but it only prints `1`. I have this in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file: `android:versionName="1.3"` which I also want to print

Answer (score 1):

If you want the versionName, then:

```
   String currentVersionName;
    try {
        currentVersionName = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                this.getApplicationInfo().packageName, 0).versionName;
        Toast.makeText(this, currentVersionName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

is more appropriate, that would work if you had

```
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="Mickey Mouse"
```

It would show "Mickey Mouse". The answer you accepted would show "1"